# How to get a collection of input elements by name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mootools, css-selectors

I've got a form which looks like that:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return new_post_form_submit();">    
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="addPost">   
<input type="hidden" name="post_photo_edit[]" value="0">    
<input type="hidden" name="post_photo_edit[]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="post_photo_edit[]" value="0">
 ... 
</form>
```

Inside `new_post_form_submit` function, I would like to select all the elements named `post_photo_edit` as a collection. As You can see it name actually is `post_photo_edit[]`, because I want to have it as an array inside my PHP code.

I'm using MooTools, but probably jQuery will have exactly the same solution for this.

I've tried to call

```
$$("input[name='post_photo_edit[]']")
```

but it gave me an exception. And calling it this way:

```
$$("input[name='post_photo_edit']")
```

returns empty collection.

I know I can call this instead

```
document.getElementsByName("post_photo_edit[]")
```

and it will work perfect, but I'm wondering how this expression should look like in MooTools to work like this above.

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Function: $$**

Selects and extends DOM elements. Return an Elements instance. The Element instance returned is an array-like object, supporting every Array method and every Element method.

**Syntax:**

`var myElements = $$(argument);`

**Arguments:**

- selector - (string) A CSS selector
- elements - (elements), (collection) or (array) An enumerable list of elements
- element, element - (element) any number of elements as arguments

**Returns:**

- (elements) - An array-like Elements collection of all the DOM elements matched, extended with document:id.

So you should use: `$$(document.getElementsByName("post_photo_edit[]"));`

CSS3 supports character escaping, so you can use backslashes to escape characters:

But you can also escape the array operator like this: `$$("input[name=post_photo_edit\[\]]")`

Comment: this `$$("input[name=post_photo_edit\[\]]")` would be perfect, but it doesn't work

Comment: i tried in jsfiddle under google chrome and it was good.
http://jsfiddle.net/WSkQs/

Comment: Your're right, it's working but... I'm using some old MooTools version, under 1.1 on jsfiddle it also do not work, under 1.25 it return 0 and under 1.3 it works as it should. Thank You!

Comment: If you're trying to use Mootools/do this to get around IE8's DOM traversal limitations, this doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about MooTools, but to select every elemnt that has an attribute which BEGINS with something, you do this:

```
$('input[name^="post_photo_edit"]')
```

You can check it out here: [jQuery starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Thank You for Your tip, it's `$$('input[name^="post_photo_edit"]')` actually. MooTools is using [W3C CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Comment: Under IE, a least 8, only this works: `[name~='post_photo_edit']`

Answer (score 1):

you should use [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). It's same on MooTools